# SQL Server datetime in 12AM/PM format without the millisecond

Tags: sql-server

I would like to return my datetime data to the following format:

mm/dd/yy hh:mi:ssAM

According to the CONVERT [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the closest thing that matches my spec is '131'

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 131)
```

but it doesn't exactly match my specifications.

---

EDIT:
I ended up doing the date formatting in my application layer which is PHP.

It was as simple as using the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to generate a UNIX timestamp and pass it into `date` funciton.

```
$date = date('m/d/Y g:ia', strtotime($row['date_time']));
```

Comment: Transact-SQL isn't a language built for text manipulation, or string  formatting. Generally, if you need to perform such exact formatting, you do better using the text formatting facilities available in whichever tool is consuming your result.

Comment: @Daminen.  You are right.  I ended up doing the date formatting in my application layer (php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101) + 
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 0),REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(),107), ',',''),'')
```

This basically uses a method that's what you want for the DATE, then adds it to the time portion of what you want for the time only.

Comment: @Martin - true.  It also seems to parse some of the dates in a strange way.  You could bypass your issue with `DECLARE @dt datetime = GETDATE()` and then subbing in `@dt` for `GETDATE()`

Comment: I realised after commenting that the OP is likely using this against a column rather than `getdate()` so my comment is irrelevant!

Answer (score 2):

Although I feel that formatting should really be part of the UI, I guess if you really need it the below works - I'm sure there is an easier way to do this - but make this a UDF, and just use it in whatever query you want.

```
declare @date varchar(50)
set @date = (select CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 131))
set @date = (select LEFT(@date,len(@date) - 6) + ' ' + RIGHT(@date,2))
set @date = right(@date,LEN(@date) - 11)

select CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101) + @date
```

Comment: +1 it works and is less ugly than either of the other two (one of which is mine :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can assemble it from DATEPART()'s, and create a user defined function from it for easy re-use.

This is untested off the top of my head.. give it a shot:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnSpecDate()
 RETURNS VARCHAR(24)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @outData VARCHAR(24)

set @outData = 
       CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())) + "/"
       + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(dd,GETDATE())) + "/"
       + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(yy,GETDATE())) + " "
       + CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) > 12 
                THEN CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) - 12)
              WHEN DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) = 0
                THEN '12'
              ELSE CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()))
         END + ":"
       + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())) + ":"
       + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(ss,GETDATE()))
       + CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) > 11 
                THEN "PM"
              ELSE "AM"
         END

RETURN @outData

END
```

Then in any regular query, you can just include `dbo.fnSpecDate() as myDate`